# Using Selenium RC with PHP without terminal?

Tags: php, selenium-rc

I am looking into using Selenium RC with PHP but so far, all examples require that you use the terminal to run the php script. Isn't it possible to just run the php file and selenium code without access to terminal?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, as long as the PHP program is allowed to make remote HTTP requests to the Selenium RC.

But you might need to adjust the **maximum execution time** if needed:

Reference: http://www.linuxask.com/questions/set-the-maximum-execution-time-in-php